# PHP - Jobs/Queue - Class dispatch does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I am trying to use queues in Laravel, and have installed Redis and Horizon for this purpose.

My users can upload images through a frontend. When this happens, it calls a `store` method:

```
public function store(Stream $stream)
{
    //Validate the request.
    $validate = request()->validate([
        'file' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png,gif,pdf',
    ]);

    ImportDocuments::dispatch($stream);
}
```

In my `Jobs/ImportDocuments.php` class, I have this code:

```
class ImportDocuments implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $stream;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param  Document  $document
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Stream $stream)
    {
        $this->stream = $stream;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //Store the actual document. returns the path.
        $store = request()->file('file')->store($this->stream->token);

        //Set the attributes to save to DB.
        $attributes['name'] = request()->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $attributes['path'] = $store;

        //Add the document to the database.
        $this->stream->addDocuments($attributes);
    }
}
```

For your reference, the `addDocuments()` method look like this:

`Stream.php`:

```
public function addDocuments(array $attributes)
{
    return $this->documents()->create($attributes);
}
```

Whenever I try to upload an image, I get below error:

```
Class dispatch does not exist {"userId":1,"email":"myemail@myapp.com","exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class dispatch does not exist at /Users/MyUsername/Sites/playground/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:779)
```

- Redis is running
- predis/predis is installed
- Horizon is running
- Horizon status says 'Active'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably not the problem, but I don't think you'll be able to pull in the request() like that.  You're not in the controller anymore and the request has come and gone.  I think you should take whatever you need from the request and pass it into the job constructor.

Comment: @TarekAdam Good point. I changed it to accept `Request $request` - but still the same error.

Comment: ya, kinda figured that wasn't gonna solve it.  I just happen to be working a controller/job scenario ~ so Im trying to recreate the error within my own context.

Comment: Is Stream just an Orm model?

Comment: Yes, just a basic model created with `php artisan make:model`.

Comment: My controller is located in a subfolder called “/Streams” don’t know if that changes anything

Comment: The static ::dispatch(...args...) is overly complicated and relies on __destruct() and such.  I haven't had good luck with that, as well as the 'SerializesModels' trait.  I have not been able to re-create your issue, but if youi'll humor me, try: 1) old style dispatch(new Job(...)) and also remove SerializesModels from your job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189417/discussion-between-tarek-adam-and-oliverbj).

Comment: you sure request can get the data from a job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the answer was actually quite simple, yet very frustrating.

I am using `valet` with Laravel, and was accessing my site at: `mywebsite.test`. I tried to load it through:

`php artisan serve`, and then tried the exact same thing, just from the IP (`127.0.0.1`) - and then it worked!

So I just restarted valet, and then it worked there as well.

```
valet restart
```

And bam it worked..